# Cannot launch AVD in android studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I know this question have been asked so many times but I have exhausted all the options on SO and other platforms as well and idk what to do anymore. I have installed HAXM, I have tried to set the path to the right folder, installed/uninstalled the thing, and what's worse I tried to uninstall again today and there is an error saying it cant find uninstall.exe I have an important project in another 2 months and my phone's USB port is faulty so I cant run my apps in it. please help

Comment: What is the OS?

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to the folder where you have installed your Android Sdk and if you don't know then go to File in Android Studio and select Project Structure like this

[image]

Then Select Sdk Location where you will get the path of your Android Sdk.

Then go to AndroidSdk/emulator folder and open cmd,

Then type this command ----   emulator -list-avds   ----
After that you will get list of the emulators installed and then run another command ----  emulator -avd "The exact name of device you want to run" and press enter.

The emulator will start if it doesn't it means you have some errors in system - image. You can solve it by deleting the previous system image then download new one.

The slashes are just to differentiate the command, nothing else.

Comment: I tried but "C:\Users\i19328>emulator -list
'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." came out